# How to prevent Passenger with Nginx from stoping

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, passenger, redmine

Need some help.
I have a problem with Passenger with nginx.

Data:
Ubuntu 20.04
Passenger Fusion 6.0.7
nginx 1.18.0
ruby 2.6.0p0

On server I have Redmine application.

Now the problem is that Passenger is shutting down nginx or rather disconnecting 'long running process' every day because of inactivity.

my nix config file for domain:

```
server {
    server_name xpo-asos.industrial-engineering.co;
    root /home/seven/xpobarnsley.industrial-engineering.co/public/;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
     }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env production;

    location /cable {
      passenger_app_group_name myapp_websocket;
      passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
    }

    # Allow uploads up to 100MB in size
    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location ~ ^/(assets|packs) {
      expires max;
      gzip_static on;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xpo-asos.industrial-engineering.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xpo-asos.industrial-engineering.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = xpo-asos.industrial-engineering.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_app_env production;

    location /cable {
      passenger_app_group_name myapp_websocket;
      passenger_force_max_concurrent_requests_per_process 0;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name xpo-asos.industrial-engineering.co;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Any idea?

Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for an update. I did not found why Passenger was crashing all the time.
I did remove the module and installed puma, which I highly recommend to all for running Ruby apps.